# How do I replace the text to a link generated by a wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

I have created a function that works with SOME text but not all. I am try to replace Cookbook to All Recipes. It works fine on some instances not all. The one specifically I am trying to target is a link text.

This is what I have that works on other Cookbook text, but not the link I am targeting.

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case 'Cookbook' :
        $translated_text = __( 'All Recipes' );
        break;
}
return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Here is the element code I am targeting:

```
<span class="145-test 120-test 115-test loaded-header">Cookbook</span>
```

to this.

```
<span class="145-test 120-test 115-test loaded-header">All Recipes</span>



This does not work:

function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case '<span class="145-test 120-test 115-test loaded-header">Cookbook</span>' :
        $translated_text = __( '<span class="145-test 120-test 115-test loaded-header">All Recipes</span>' );
        break;
}
return $translated_text;
}
 add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

I am willing to go the Javascript or JQuery mode, but I want it try it the PHP way first.

Comment: Please put more examples where the code is not working well.

Comment: This is the only link Im targeting, sorry I dont have other examples.<span class="145-test 120-test 115-test loaded-header">Cookbook</span>